# Unity how many character rig sprite hierarchy for a 2D top down game are needed and how to transition?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 2d, topdown

I am building a 2D top-down game in Unity and I am new to Unity.

The player character can face North, South, East and West.

For each direction, the character faces, he can remain Idle, Walk or Attack.

I am currently using a character rig method to do the animations. So, each part of the player which can move, is a game object sprite. E.g. Head is one game object, upper left leg, lower left leg, left foot are all separate game objects.

The animations clip is created in Unity.

The sprites used for each direction the character faces are also different, e.g. when the character faces North, we will see the back of the head of the character but when the character faces South, we will see the character full face.

I got a few of questions:

1. Does this mean, I have to create a set of game objects for each mode (idle, walk, attack) in the 4 directions (N,S,W & E)? 3x4 = 12 sets of game objects sprites?
2. How to make only 1 set of game objects appear at only 1 time? E.g. only 1 set appear, only Idle facing south can appear but the rest of the directions and modes should be "hidden"?
3. How do I transition from 1 mode to another mode? E.g. from idle facing South to walking facing East to attacking facing North?

Comment: Guessing you got downvoted for asking too many questions at once, but these are all questions that, IMO, aren't discussed enough regarding rigged sprites and 2D top-down, so I upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you tried Anima2D - it is free Unity plugin by Unity Technologies for animating 2D characters using bones. It makes animation process much more faster and easier. There are some helpful videos about Anima2D:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lG4AeOriIco&

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhOJ742NSoM&

Now about your questions:

1. If you want to see your character in different viewes, you have to make at least 3 groups of GameObjects (front, back and profile - turned right or left).
   But you don't have to make different groups for character turned right or left. You can just change transform.scale.x to -1 or 1. For example:

   ```
    if(/*Character is turned right*/){
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    } else if(/*Character is turned left*/){
        //This will mirrow you character
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    }
   ```

   But if you want to make difference between right side and left side of your character, you have to make two different groups of GameObjects.
2. You can use GameObject.SetActive to turn off or turn on some GameObjects in scene.
   For example let's imagine that you have this structure of GameObjects:
   [Structure of GameObjects (Your script is on Player)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6N8z.png)
   Then you can use such code:

   ```
    //Choose any name for class
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
        //Enum for states of player
        enum state{
            Front = 0,
            Back = 1,
            Profile = 2
        }

        //Set 0th to Front state GO, 1st to Back state GO, 2nd to Profile state GO in inspector
        [SerializeField]
        private List<GameObject> parentsForEachState;
        //Field to know current state and current set of GameObjects to show
        private state currentState = state.Front;

        void SwitchState(state newState){
            for(int i = 0; i < 3/*Number of states*/; i++){
                if(i == (int)newState){
                    parentsForEachState[i].SetActive(true);
                } else {
                    parentsForEachState[i].SetActive(false);
                }
                //Also set animation of parentsForEachState[newState] to what you want
                currentState = newState;
            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. I don't see any variant to make smooth transition between theese states. So I recommend just to switch GameObjects as I've shown in previous code. You also can use standart Unity animation transitions to make it smoother. So I recommend you to switch from Idle South to Idle East and then switch from Idle East to Walking East. This will look better then just switching from Idle South to Walking East.